# Here Maps: How to get routeId from Here fleet telemetry api?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I calculate a route using the Here Fleet telemetry APIs and after that, I want to Navigate to the same route which calculated earlier. so, Is that possible to get the routeId from the fleet API and then call the getRoute endpoint to fetch the previously calculated route? if not, Is there any other way?

I use enterprise licence for Here Maps.

I calculate with the below URL:
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?driver_cost=10.00&vehicle_cost=0.257&currency=EUR&apiKey=MYAPIKEY&routeAttributes=shape%2Csummary%2CsummaryByCountry%2CboundingBox&alternatives=0&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&limitedWeight=2t&height=4m&width=2.55m&length=16.5m&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&emissionType=7&fuelType=diesel&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=8500&tiresCount=12&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=3m&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&rollups=none%2Ccountry%3Btollsys&waypoint0=geo%21stopOver%2145.88592269999999%2C10.8421329&waypoint1=geo%21stopOver%2148.0296441%2C16.3793614&waypoint2=geo%21stopOver%2150.73743%2C7.0982068

Answer (score 0):

You can use HERE Fleet Telematics API (Route Matching) which will help you create a route and use that route as an overlay. As a customer, you can create, use, and update multiple overlay maps. For example, one overlay map with changes for waste collection vehicles, and another map with changes for oversize transports.

Could you please have a look at the following to have a better understanding.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-matching/dev_guide/topics/custom-routes.html

You can also have a hands-on experience using the following link.

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/custom_routing_basic.